# How to load JSON basic

Tags: javascript, json

I posted this question to understand why this works with Gravatar and not in a typical production environment. The answer was simple but something I overlooked because I am new to working with JSON and assumed the issue was my understanding of it. This forum was absolutely no help in understanding that Gravatar's back-end is simply using server side script to output Javascript when the callback is used and plain JSON when only the URL to the JSON is accessed. Thus making this script work, because it is script being output.

Although the first part of the question was responded to, and helpful, the later part of discovering how this was possible with Gravatar was completely ignored. Because only half of this question was commented on, I would like this thread removed. Thanks.

---

I have been working with some JSON projects and I continue to run into an error, time and again.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

The index.html is as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="es"/>
    <script type="application/javascript" async="true" defer="true" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" async="true" defer="true" src="flag.json?callback=pFlag"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function pFlag(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

flag.json

```
{"flag":{"color":"green"}}
```

I have another project using these same principle that does not produce this error.

http://lib.richardkentgates.com/gravacon/

What gives?

Comment: Ok, it is too late.. but here is the very useful and genuine link for json - 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC

Answer (score 4):

Never going to work like that. you're loading your `flag.json` as an external script, which means the file has to contain valid JS code. What you have is not actual code, it's just a JS value definition. External scripts must basically be the contents of a `<script>` tag block, WITHOUT the script tag.
e.g

```
var foo = {"flag":{"color":"green"}};
```

would work.

Given the `callback` business in your url, you're probably trying to do a JSONP-type request, which means `flag.json` should actually contain this:

```
pFlag({"flag":{"color":"green"}})
```

Comment: I second the JSONP portion of this answer. JSONP requires a supporting distant end (to wrap the JSON output in a call to the named function), and cannot work with a direct request to a static JSON file.

Comment: So then neither of you have looked at the example I posted. This is exactly the way Gravatar provides it's data. Please look at the functioning example I posted and not just cherry pick the question.

Comment: then perhaps you should go look at your own example as well. your gravatar `<script>` is **NOT** returning a bare json value. it's returning properly formed JSONP, which is the **ONLY** way such a thing could possibly work. just because the url being used has `.json` in it doesn't mean you're hitting a json file. filename extensions in urls are utterly **MEANINGLESS**. a webmaster could rename all their .html files to .exe and serve up `http://example.com/runme.exe`. that doesn't mean you're running an executable on that server...

Comment: @MarcB ok, I think you get the purpose of this post. I would really appreciate if you could expand on this a little. I don't see any structural difference in the JSON v JSONP schema and I have tried to output the application/json and application/javascript headers in my .htaccess. So how is Gravatar making this happen? I would really appreciate some pointers here. Both so I can understand what they are doing and the best way to properly load JSON data to be worked with post page load. Thanks in advance. Please keep CORS restrictions in mind.

Comment: jsonp is literally just the text of a a JS function call, `somefunc(somejson)`. that's it. your file contains ONLY `somejson`, which is not valid. go read what jsonp is - you're not using it correctly.

Comment: @MarcB My mistake. I guess you din't understand my post. I understand what you are saying. The part that is missing from any of these responses is how this is working with Gravater. I don't understand why there are so many responses that avoid looking at what Gravater is doing and why it works. Gravtar is widely used, mainly by WordPress, so if they are doing something that makes this work, I think it's of sufficient interest to understand.

Comment: go to your url, view the source, click on the url in the `<script>` that hits gravatar. you'll get `/**/gravacon.functionObject.gravatar({"entry": blah blah blah`. Note that that's a FUNCTION CALL. it's not pure json. it's a jsonp response, which is a function call with the json data as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
<script type="application/javascript" async="true" defer="true" src="flag.json?callback=pFlag"></script>
```

JSON is [based on a subset of JavaScript](http://www.json.org/), but it is not actually JavaScript. You cannot call your .json file as a script (i.e., using a `<script>` tag). Instead, you should load it using [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).